# php imagejpeg path in laravel broken

Tags: php, path, laravel, laravel-3, base-path

my imagejpeg function is failing on my remote website, works fine locally.

This is the code I'm using at the moment wich works fine locally.

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, path('public') . 'thumbnails/' . $filename ,$jpeg_quality);
```

When I try it out on my remote website I get:

> Unable to open
>   '/home/deb65018/domains/mywebsite.com/designs/public/thumbnails/1308341733389.jpg'
>   for writing: No such file or directory

I've tried this aswell:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, URL::base() . '/thumbnails/' . $filename ,$jpeg_quality);
```

But using the basepath somehow breaks my code even locally by giving me a "Unable to open" error.

Can anyone point out my stupid mistakes?

Comment: have you tried URL::to('public') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the log,
Usually are located here /var/log/httpd/error.log in linux or easier turn on display errors in php [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)
In this way you can check with more detail the error